# Getting the current master volume in Java

Tags: java, volume, javasound

I have Clip plaiong on my app and I'd like to get either the master volume or the volume of the Clip that is playing... I am fairly new to this.

Here's the code where i play the audio:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/music/music.wav"));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
clip.start();
clip.loop(-1);
```

Comment: You have to work with File object. Please consult JavaDoc.

Comment: Im not having a problem with the files... i fixed that a long time ago

Comment: Ok, so you are asking about "other" volume. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float volume = clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME).getValue();
```

You should probably look at Java's API entry for [FloatControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.html).

Comment: gives me a IllegalArgumentException :/

Comment: So is it giving you an IllegalArgumentException or 0.0, which is it?

Comment: the code he gave me gives me an exeption... with MASTER_GAIN it always returns 0.0

Comment: I see. It appears VOLUME is not a supported control.

As for MASTER_GAIN, that's because ["Gain is a quantity in decibels (dB) that is added to the intrinsic decibel level of the audio signal - that is, the level of the signal before it is altered by the gain control...The gain setting defaults to a value of 0.0 dB, meaning the signal's loudness is unaffected."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.Type.html#MASTER_GAIN)

Comment: Perhaps you want the instantaneous RMS or dB (the volume 'at that moment' as perceived by the user)?  That can only be found by processing the sound sample frames in chunks.